# How to read these algebraic formulas?

Tags: readings, mathematics

I am reading a Japanese text, but i wonder how to read these set and function formulas:

> A∪B={x|x∈A または x∈B}
>
> P(X)={A|A⊂X}

How do you read these in Japanese?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how I would read it.

> A∪B={x|x∈A または x∈B}
>   AとBの和集合とはAまたはBにあるxからなる集合のことです。

> P(X)={A|A⊂X}
>   ピ（・オブ）・エックスとはXの全ての部分集合からなる集合のことです。

Comment: I think that's how you *explain* the formulae to others in Japanese. 音読している時に（そもそも音読あんまりしないけど…）こういう読み方，します？

Comment: @Yosh I agree with you, the "reading" I proposed is to explain the formulae. Maybe if someone want to embed the formula in another clause (s)he can use: ”AとBの和集合を、AとBの要素からなる集合として...” or ”AカップBを、AとBの要素からなる集合として...”.

Answer (score 2):

The following site shows how to pronounce some mathematical formulas:
http://izumi-math.jp/sanae/report/suusiki/suusiki.htm